# modified hollow star pattern - outputs grid pattern

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm trying to create a program where you input an integer, and it outputs a grid pattern equal to the input. For example, if you input 3, it creates a 3x3 pattern, if you input 4, it creates a 4x4 pattern,and so on.

To better visualize what I'm trying to say, see the example outputs below.

1 ↵

```
*
```

2 ↵

```
* * * 
* * * 
* * *
```

3 ↵

```
* * * * * * *
*   *   *   *
* * * * * * *
*   *   *   *
* * * * * * *
*   *   *   *
* * * * * * *
```

4 ↵

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * 
*     *     *     *     * 
*     *     *     *     * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * 
*     *     *     *     * 
*     *     *     *     * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * 
*     *     *     *     * 
*     *     *     *     * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * 
*     *     *     *     * 
*     *     *     *     * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

#### FIX:

I've converted Razvan's code to only use `for-loops` and `if-else` statements for better visualization:

```java
int input, numberOfLines, emptySpaceCount;
input = 4;
numberOfLines = input * (input - 1) + 1;
emptySpaceCount = 2 * input - 3;

if (input < 1) {
  System.out.println("Invalid input!");

} else if (input == 1) {
  System.out.println("*");

} else {
  for (int a = 0; a < numberOfLines; a++) {
    if (a % (input - 1) == 0) {
      for (int b = 0; b < numberOfLines; b++) {
        System.out.print("--");
      }
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
        System.out.print("|");
        for (int j = 0; j < emptySpaceCount; j++) {
          System.out.print(" ");
        }
      }
      System.out.print("|");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

it outputs

```
------------------------- 
|     |     |     |     | 
|     |     |     |     | 
------------------------- 
|     |     |     |     | 
|     |     |     |     | 
------------------------- 
|     |     |     |     | 
|     |     |     |     | 
------------------------- 
|     |     |     |     | 
|     |     |     |     | 
-------------------------
```

Comment: We don't usually answer this sort of question here. The best way to get a good response here is to try it yourself and then show us where you are stuck.

Comment: Thanks. Is my updated version right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after gaining a bit more experience, I revisited this problem and came up with a better solution

Basically, this program takes an integer as input that outputs a grid pattern where each cell size is equal to that input. The hollow pattern was just the first part of the checker like pattern problem that was given to us.

Anyways, here's my solution:

### Main Method:

So we first have to get the user's input

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int cellSize = console.nextInt();
    console.close();
```

then we use this formula:

```java
    int gridSize = cellSize * (cellSize - 1);
    int cellSizeInGrid = (gridSize + 1) / cellSize;
```

I know, not the greatest variable names out there, but hey as long as it is understandable I'm fine with it.

Moving on, the core on program basically goes like this.

```java
    for (int row = 0; row <= gridSize; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col <= gridSize; col++) {
        if (isGridBorder(row, col, gridSize) || isCellBorder(row, col, cellSizeInGrid, cellSize)) {
          System.out.print("* ");
        } else {
          System.out.print("  ");
        }
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
```

and then

### Helper Methods

```java
  private static boolean isGridBorder(int row, int col, int boardSize) {
    return row == 0 || col == 0 || row == boardSize || col == boardSize;
  }

  private static boolean isCellBorder(int row, int col, int cellSizeInGrid, int cellSize) {
    return row % cellSizeInGrid == cellSizeInGrid- (cellSize - 1)
        || col % cellSizeInGrid == cellSizeInGrid- (cellSize - 1);
  }
```

Anyways were done.

### Adding more patterns

with this layout, we can easily add more patterns to the grid, for example if you want to make it have alternating fills, we just modify our `if` blocks like so:

```java
        if (isGridBorder(row, col, gridSize) || isCellBorder(row, col, cellSizeInGrid, cellSize)
            || isFilled(row, col, cellSizeInGrid)) {
          System.out.print("* ");
        } else {
          System.out.print("  ");
        }
```

then we add this method:

```java
  private static boolean isFilled(int row, int col, int cellSizeInGrid) {
    return ((row / cellSizeInGrid) + (col / cellSizeInGrid)) % 2 == 0;
  }
```

---

Well, that's about it, I guess

Answer (score 2):

Generally when you see multiple loops nested inside each other, you might think there's something wrong with the design. You can simplify the problem if you consider printing the big picture line-by-line. You have 2 kinds of lines:

- Border line (made full of stars)
- Inner line (which only has stars for the vertical columns)

So the main function should look something like this:

```
void hollowSquares(int number) {
    // Default cases
    if (number < 1) {
        return;
    }
    if (number == 1) {
        System.out.println("*");
        return;
    }
    
    // how many lines will be actually printed
    int numberOfLines = number * (number - 1) + 1;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
        if (isBorderLine(i, number)) {
            printBorderLine(numberOfLines);
        } else {
            printInnerLine(number);
        }
    }   
}

boolean isBorderLine(int line, int number) {
    return line % (number - 1) == 0;
}
```

So the only thing left to do is the actual printing. For the simpler case, border line, you repeat the star-and-space pattern:

```
void printBorderLine(int numberOfLines) {
    String line = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(numberOfLines, "* "));
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

For the inner border, you want to repeat the start-and-a-couple-spaces pattern, followed by a trailing star

```
void printInnerLine(int number) {
    int numberOfEmptySpaces = 2 * number - 3;
    String emptySpaces = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(numberOfEmptySpaces, " "));
    String starWithSpacesPattern = "*" + emptySpaces;
    String line = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(number, starWithSpacesPattern));
    line += "*"; // trailing star
    System.out.println(line);
}
```